# Is there a base form for fieldable entity settings?

Tags: entities, 8

I've build custom entity by extending `ContentEntityBase` class. It's very similar to the entity from `content_entitity_example`.

I'd like to allow users to manage fields display the same way they can do it with nodes. Is there a base form class that can generate the form for fields display settings automatically?

The example module provides entity settings form that is derived from `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase` however it does not provide any form fields for managing the entity view settings - the form is just empty.

Comment: You have to define field ui route in your entity annotation in order for field ui to attach itself to your entity and provide you with their goodies.

Comment: @IvanJaros Can you be more specific? I've used `field_ui_base_route` in entity annotation but that doesn't seem to change anything. Could that might be caused by the fact that I've set `fieldable` property of my entity to `true` AFTER it was enabled?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. This was something else. Extending the \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm should be enough. The \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm::form call entity form display which is responsible for the fields so that should be all. Maybe you haven't declared the edit form in entity annotation? ... no i see you have mentioend the FormBase, yeah, do not use that one, use the ContentEntityForm.

Comment: @IvanJaros I'm not asking about entity edit/create forms. I'm asking about entity settings form where you can fields to the entity and manage their view settings.

Comment: In that case my first answer is the correct one. Do you have entity type entity for your entity - like Node Type is for Node? also that field ui route should point to that entity type entity collection/listing, not to the content entity one.

Comment: I suppose `fieldable` property does not make sense any longer. Try `field_ui_base_route` as was suggested above.